# How can I change version to specified number pattern?

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to compare version record and get latest version

Table contains version list if I select like this

```
SELECT MainVersion From DBVersion

1.4.0.58
1.4.0.59
1.4.0.60
1.4.0.61
1.4.0.62
1.4.0.67
1.4.1.2
1.4.0.64
1.4.0.65
1.4.0.66
```

If I select like this, I'd like to get
this will split by '.' and each version field will be PadLeft with '0' x 3

```
SELECT GetLatestVersion(MainVersion) From DBVersion

001004000058
001004000059
001004000060
001004000061
001004000062
001004000067
001004001002
001004000064
001004000065
001004000066
```

so I could get like this

```
SELECT TOP(1) GetLatestVersion(MainVersion) From DBVersion ORDER BY 1 DESC

001004001002
```

Would it be there a way if I could convert like this?

Comment: What have you tried? There are string splitting functions in SQL Server

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this problem yourself? What specific part of it are you having difficulties with?

Answer (score 0):

With that sample data you could use [`parsename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`convert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to order numerically to get the latest version.

```
SELECT TOP 1
       nmuloc
       FROM dbversion
       ORDER BY convert(integer, parsename(nmuloc, 4)) DESC,
                convert(integer, parsename(nmuloc, 3)) DESC,
                convert(integer, parsename(nmuloc, 2)) DESC,
                convert(integer, parsename(nmuloc, 1)) DESC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7d679e55c66deee034d37a5ff3982aff)